# Is there any session storage in Bixby other than $vivContext?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Can we store concept value or action name values in session or is there any temporary storage?

I only found $vivContext which is available all across the session but we cant store the values there also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default concepts are stored across a session/conversation (mark them as transient if you do not want this behavior e.g. make them request based). However to store across sessions, you need to use an API call.

Answer (score 1):

Bixby doesn't support anything like this.

If you wish to store things across sessions, it's highly recommended that you use you own third-party storage solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [tutorial capsule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678301/microphone-input-error-in-bixby-studio-simulator-on-a-mac) that uses an AWS dynamoDB for remote storage. It includes step-by-step instructions for how to use AWS for storing things between sessions. Please feel free to clone or fork it, and customize it for your needs.