# Microphone input error in Bixby Studio Simulator on a Mac

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am trying to use the microphone input on the Bixby Studio Simulator.
When I press either the mic button or the space bar, the command windows shows 'Listening...' but after a second it stops and shows an error dialog.
I've check the Audio section in the Mac's System Preference and the audio input is working correctly. However I cannot find any audio settings in Bixby Studio. What else do I need to check?

[image: Error Dialog]

Comment: Hi @Alan, you've probably encountered a bug. Please go `Help` > `Contact Support` in the application menu to submit diagnostics data so the team can fix the issue. Also, if you notice a System Permission prompt for Microphone Access, please accept.

Comment: @JosiahRuddell This issue happens on both of the Macs I've installed Bixby Studio on. Also I've checked System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Microphone but I do not see BixbyStudio in the list.

Just submitted a bug ticket: https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/requests/3465

Comment: Thank you! @Alan We will submit to our IDE team.